# django formset displaying wrong objects

Tags: django, formset

when creating a new recipe post, I use two formsets for ingredients and directions. however, **the new post formsets are being populated by existing ingredient and direction objects when they should be empty**. here is my view for the new post and the forms:

```
def post_new(request):
    form = PostForm()
    ingredient_form = IngredientFormSet(prefix='ingredient_form')
    direction_form = DirectionFormSet(prefix='ingredient_form')

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        ingredient_form = IngredientFormSet(request.POST, prefix='ingredient_form')
        direction_form = DirectionFormSet(request.POST, prefix='direction_form')

        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()

            if ingredient_form.is_valid():
                    for i_form in ingredient_form:
                        if i_form.is_valid() and i_form.has_changed():
                            i_form.instance.recipe = post
                            i_form.save()

            if direction_form.is_valid():
                    for d_form in direction_form:
                        if d_form.is_valid() and d_form.has_changed():
                            d_form.instance.recipe = post
                            d_form.save()

            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)

    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form, 'ingredient_form': ingredient_form, 'direction_form': direction_form})
```

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'image', 'text', 'prep_time', 'cook_time', 'servings_first', 'servings_second', 'tags']


IngredientFormSet = modelformset_factory(Ingredient, fields=['name',
                                                            'int_amount',
                                                            'float_amount',
                                                            'measurement'
                                                            ], extra=15)



DirectionFormSet = modelformset_factory(Direction, fields=['text',
                                                            'order'
                                                            ], extra=25)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it is needed, but setting each formsets query to "None" solved the problem:

```
def post_new(request):
    form = PostForm()
    ingredient_form = IngredientFormSet(queryset=Ingredient.objects.none(), prefix='ingredient_form')
    direction_form = DirectionFormSet(queryset=Direction.objects.none(), prefix='ingredient_form')
```